# My \b is not printing correctly in Python 3.6 in IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I am trying to print backspaces to continually overwrite text but the backspace is printing a value and not overwriting.

Idle with Python 3.6.4 with IDLEX extension installed.

> > > print('foo\bar')
> > >       fooar

It should be printing foar instead of fooar.

Comment: Weird, it is not displaying what it shows in the console.   Console shows foo*ar where * similar to a long vertical rectangle.  Equivalent to [] but completely closed.  It did not show up for SO description.

Comment: May be IDLE specific, works for me in the command line.

Comment: IDLE may not use real console/terminal but own function to simulate console and it may not have all functionalities

Comment: This is entirely terminal dependent. Python is merely outputting (the byte encoding of) a 6-characters string.

Comment: This is a duplicate of multiple python-idle backspace questions.  I picked the one that seems most useful, and added comments there.